# manual bin size selection in R ggplot geom.tile function?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way I can manually set bin sizes that do not have same size and colour them after specific colour codes?

I want to have a heatmap with binsizes: 0-0.05, 0.05-0.25, 0.25-0.5, 0.5-0.75 and 0.75-1
For bin 0-0.05 I want to have the set colour: `"#ecefb7"` for the remaining bins I want to have a gradient from `low="#7fc8b9"` to `high="#3a81b5"`.

I did manage to get the bins in my legend, but not with the specific color coding. Does perhaps anyone know how I can achieve this?

Sample minimal data:

```
    Group sample     pvalue
1   OG0000010:Up  EB1_D 0.04900000
2 OG0000050:Down  EB1_D 0.19019725
3   OG0000638:Up  EB1_D 0.52008137
4   OG0000010:Up  EN1_D         NA
5   OG0000050:Down  EN1_D 0.01615993
6 OG0000638:Up  EN1_D 0.48958058
```

The code I use so far:

```
ggplot(pvaldata2, aes(x=sample, y=Group)) + 
  geom_tile(colour="black", size=0.25, aes(fill=pvalue)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="#ecefb7", high="#3a81b5", na.value = "white",
                      breaks = c(0.05, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75), 
                      labels = c("0.05", "0.25", "0.5", "0.75")) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8))
```

The resulting heatmap but still with the wrong bin colours:
[image]

Comment: Use `cut` to break the continuous variable into intervals, then use a sequential fill scale like the ones from ColorBrewer (or make your own)

Comment: fyi, it's nicer to use `dput` to supply sample data as that can be pasted directly into R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get complete control over the colour scale by changing to `scale_fill_gradientn`, setting `limits` to `c(0, 1)`, specfiying all your colours in a vector, and their location as a vector in `values`. In your case that would look like this:

```r
ggplot(pvaldata2, aes(x = sample, y = Group)) + 
  geom_tile(colour="black", size = 0.25, aes(fill = pvalue)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c(rep("#ecefb7", 2), "#7fc8b9", "#3a81b5"),
                       na.value = "white",
                       values = c(0, 0.05, 0.0501, 1),
                       limits = c(0, 1)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8))
```

[image]

As you can see, this has coloured the `NA` white, the p values below 0.05 (even those very close to 0.05) in the desired buff colour, and the rest in the chosen gradient.